# hello i have trouble with php code scrabble point counter but in Latvian

Tags: php

So strait to chase

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1); // strict ment

function punktudaudzums($mot){
    
    $b10punkti = array("f","ģ","h","ķ","č");
    $b8punkti = array("ļ","ž");
    $b6punkti = array("ņ","š","ū");
    $b5punkti = array("b","c","g");
    $b4punkti = array("ē","ī","j");
    $b3punkti = array("d","o","v","z");
    $b2punkti = array("ā","k","l","m","n","p");
    $b1punkti = array("a","e","i","r","s","t","u");
    
    //$mot = utf8_encode($mot);

    $total = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($mot) ; $i++) {
        //echo strlen($mot);
        $char = $mot[$i];
        //echo $char;
        if (in_array($char, $b10punkti)) {
            $total += 10;
        }
        elseif (in_array($char, $b8punkti)) {
            $total += 8;
        }
        elseif (in_array($char, $b6punkti)) {
            $total += 6;
        }
        elseif (in_array($char, $b5punkti)) {
            $total += 5;
        }   
        elseif (in_array($char, $b4punkti)) {
            $total += 4;
        }   
        elseif (in_array($char, $b3punkti)) {
            $total += 3;    
        }
        elseif (in_array($char, $b2punkti)) {
            $total += 2;    
        }
        else{
            $total += 1;
        }
    }
    return $total;
}


//echo punktudaudzums("f\xC4\xA3h\xC4\xB7\xC4\x8D");

echo punktudaudzums("fģhķč");

//('f\xC4\xA3h\xC4\xB7\xC4\x8D')

//$b10punkti = array("f","ģ","h","ķ","č");

//print_r($b10punkti);
```

it is program that gives values to characters and when you give random string it counts the sum so when you give fģhķč it needs to be 50 but it is not, it outputs 26 and with utf8 32.

i tryed to encode in utf8 did not help then mb_strlen it fixed the output $mot tested in array

````
<?php
$test = array("č");
if (in_array("č", $test)) {
    echo "Got č";
}
else "does not have č";
``` im expecting 50 value
````

Comment: use [mb_strlen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php)

Comment: the value is still not 50 but 26

Comment: split the string then loop over each item in array https://3v4l.org/ElqGu with multi byte chars you cant really do `"č"[0]` https://3v4l.org/rRqrF

Comment: mb_str_split did fix the code, thankyou verry much

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution:

```
for ($i=0; $i < mb_strlen($mot); $i++) {
        $char = mb_substr($mot, $i, 1);
```

But Lawrence Cherone's solution is better:

```
foreach (mb_str_split($mot, 1) as $char) {
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).